# What is the need for SystemJS in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I am a complete beginner to Angular and Angular2. I am confused about how the workflow is structured. I have been looking at the [sample project](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#create-and-configure) that is present in the Angular2 site.

Correct me if I am wrong but what I know till now is that all the typescript is transpiled into javascript by the typescript compiler. Then the compiled javascript is actually what runs in the browser.

Now if I am importing the javascript files into typescript using ES6 import statements like the following-:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
```

**Why do I again need to use SystemJS to load them -:**

```
map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
```

I mean isn't that counter productive ? **Looking at the transpiled javascript of the ts files it shows all import statements are converted into require() statements.** **First of all how does require() work in a ES5** js file, and second if thats the case what is SystemJS doing.

This really confusing me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, the browsers don't support ES6 yet. So SystemJS helps with it. Anyways wait for a detailed answer by someone else.

Answer (score 118):

When `tsc` compiles typescript into JavaScript, you end up with a bunch of js files on your local system. They somehow need to be loaded into a browser. Since browsers don't support native ES6 module loading yet, you have two options, either put them all into your `index.html` file in the correct order of dependencies, or you can use a loader to do that all for you. You specify the root for all modules, and then all files are loaded and executed by that loader in the correct order of dependencies. There are many loaders: requirejs, webpack,  systemjs and others. In your particular case it's systemjs.

> Looking at the transpiled javascript of the ts files it shows all
>   import statements are converted into require() statements.

Yes, this is a way for `SystemJs` to load bundles. It uses `require()` and `exports` syntax because that's the `CommonJS` syntax for loading bundles and you specified this type in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
```

If you were to put `module:'es6'`, you would see that in your compiled javascript files the import and export statements are preserved. However, as mentioned before, you still can't use this syntax as browsers don't support it natively. If you were to put `module:'amd'`, you would see different syntax that uses `define()`. I guess the systemjs loader is preferred in `angular2` starter tutorial since it actually can load all module types supported by `tsc`. However, if you want to load modules as `es6` modules, you have to put `module: 'system'` in your `tsconfig.json`. It's a module system designed to adhere to `es6 modules` standard and used until there's a full support of `es6 modules` in browsers.

**How the setup works**

In your `index.html` you add the following script:

```
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
```

which is executed when `index.html` is loaded. The `import('app')` method instructs `systemjs` to load `app` module which is mapped to `app` folder in your project directory structure as specified by the configuration in `systemjs.config.js`:

```
map: {
    // our app is within the app folder
    app: 'app',
```

SystemJs looks for `main.js` file in that folder. When `app/main.js` is found and loaded into a browser, inside it's code the call of `require` is found:

```
var app_module_1 = require('./app.module');
```

and systemjs then fetches `app.module.js` file from local system. This one in turn has its own dependcies, like:

```
var core_1 = require('@angular/core');
```

And the cycle repeats - load, search for dependencie, load them and execute. And this is the way all dependecies are resolved, loaded and executed in a browser by the `systemjs`.

**Why the mappings to core @angular libraries are required**

In the `systemjs.config.ts` file there are mapping to the core `@angular` modules:

```
map: {
  ...
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
```

The first thing to understand here is that these are *mappings*, not dependencies. It means that if none of your files import `@angular/core`, it will not be loaded to a browser. However, you may see that this particular module is imported inside `app/app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
```

Now, why the mappings are there. Suppose `systemjs` loaded your `app/app.module.js` into the browser. It parses its content and finds the following:

```
var core_1 = require('@angular/core');
```

Now `systemjs` understands that it needs to resolve and load `@angular/core`. It first goes through the process of checking `mappings`, as specified in the docs:

> The map option is similar to paths, but acts very early in the
>   normalization process. It allows you to map a module alias to a
>   location or package.

I would call it a resolution by a named module. So, it finds the mapping and substitutes `@angular/core` with `node_modules/@angular/core` and this is where the real files are placed.

I think `systemjs` tries to imitate the approach used in `node.js` where you can specify a module without relative path identifiers `['/', '../', or './']`, simply like this `require('bar.js')` and `node.js`:

> then Node.js starts at the parent directory of the current module, and
>   adds /node_modules, and attempts to load the module from that
>   location.

If you wanted, you could avoid using named mappings and import by using relative path like this:

```
import {NgModule} from '../node_modules/@angular/core';
```

However, this should be done in all references to `@angular.core` in the project and lib files, including `@angular`, which is not a good solution to say the least.

Comment: @Maximus Then why are we specifying Angular2 dependencies separately in the `system.config.js`. Tell me something, the `app_module` file has all the dependencies for Angular2 so why can't we just load that and forget about mentioning the dependencies separately. The @angular/http and rxjs dependencies are specified separately, even though the http module is based on rxjs.

Comment: _Then why are we specifying Angular2 dependencies separately in the system.config.js_ - show the code where. If you mean that `'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'`, it's not a dependency entry, it's a mapping entry

Comment: @Maximus [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) go to the `system.config.js` tab. You will see all the angular2 entries are mapped out. **Why does it need to be mapped out ?** Why I am asking is because during the typescript compilation all the files are converted to modules that can be used SystemJS(no transpile needed here AFAIK), so if I have to add the absolute path of the dependencies I need to know all the nested dependencies and all the locations of that. For example I need to know `@angular/http` depends on `rxjs` and I need to provide the mapping for both of them.

Comment: @ng.newbie, updated my answer. you're right, you need to specify the mappings for all dependencies. If you don't, a browser will to tell you about that - `404 for http://localhost:3000/rxjs/Observable.js` if you comment `'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',` in the `systemjs.config.js`

Comment: No just disappointed that SystemJS cannot map transitive dependencies automatically. You I mainly come from a Java background, dependency tools like Maven download all dependencies related to a particular user defined dependency automatically. Like if I download Hibernate from Maven all dependencies of Hibernate will get downloaded automatically. Just wish Angular used a module loader like that. Will be posting a question about this soon.

Comment: ok, you can accept my answer if it answers your question. while maven is a "native" build system, systemjs or other loaders are "substitutes" module loading until native loaders - browsers - will implement the functionality.

Comment: @ng.newbie you can try [jspm](http://jspm.io/) which is a package manager built on top of SystemJS and tries to do just what you described here.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this in detail.  It's hard to find this information anywhere else.

Comment: @Tyguy, glad it helped

Comment: What a great read. I was struggling to understand how the entire ecosystem works what happens under the hood.

Comment: @Sangram, thanks, you can follow [angularindepth.com](https://blog.angularindepth.com/) publication for more in-depth topics you won't find anywhere else

Comment: Can somehow specify where the SystemJS Config is actually at in an Angular project created with Angular CLI? It does not appear to have one by default and I'm trying to figure out the right place to add SystemJS configurations.

Comment: @karns, systemjs is not used inside CLI in current versions. Webpack is the underlying build system