# Import node module to typescript/systemjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, systemjs

I am trying to use the [react blueprint library](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.usage), so I `npm install` it and then I tried to import it like:

`import { Spinner } from "@blueprintjs/core"`

I am getting `system.src.js:1051 GET http://localhost:8888/@blueprintjs/core 404 (Not Found)`

I thought that it has to do with the typings and since there is a `ts`file on the module I tried

`/// <reference path="../node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/dist/index.d.ts" />`

or

`/// <reference path="node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/dist/index.d.ts" />`

I am still getting the same error. **I am new to Typescript, how can I consume a node module like this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure SystemJS so it can find and load all necessary modules in the browser. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669906/what-is-the-need-for-systemjs-in-angular2) for general explanation. Here is complete minimal example that creates blueprint spinner:

**install prerequisites**

```
npm i @blueprintjs/core
npm i react
npm i react-dom
npm i react-addons-css-transition-group
npm i @types/react
npm i @types/react-dom
npm i @types/dom4
npm i typescript
npm i systemjs
```

**example code in test.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Spinner } from "@blueprintjs/core";

const mySpinner = <Spinner/>;

ReactDOM.render(mySpinner, document.body);
```

**example web page**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
    window.process = { env: {}};
    System.config({
        map: {
            'react': 'node_modules/react',
            'react-dom': 'node_modules/react-dom',
            'react-addons-css-transition-group': 'node_modules/react-addons-css-transition-group/index.js',
            'fbjs': 'node_modules/fbjs',
            'tether': 'node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js',
            'dom4': 'node_modules/dom4/build/dom4.max.js',
            '@blueprintjs/core': 'node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/dist',
            'classnames': 'node_modules/classnames/index.js',
            'object-assign': 'node_modules/object-assign/index.js',
            'pure-render-decorator': 'node_modules/pure-render-decorator/index.js'
        },
        packages: {
            'react': { main: 'lib/React.js' },
            'react-dom': { main: 'lib/ReactDOM.js' },
            'fbjs': {},
            '@blueprintjs/core': { main: 'index.js' },
            '@blueprintjs/core/common': { main: 'index.js' },
            '@blueprintjs/core/components': { main: 'index.js' }
        }
    });
    System.import('./test.js').then(function(t) {
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
</script>


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: It looks like SystemJS is unable to load react and react-dom using their bundles provided in `node_modules/react/dist/react.js` and `node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js`.  It can however load everything from individual source files from `node_modules/react/lib` and `node_modules/react-dom/lib`, provided that you define `process` variable in the browser.

Comment: Thx a lot. That was really helpful