# How to include npm packages in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Till now I practiced my ANgular 2 projects from angular-seed from 
[here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html)

While doing with this project ,I use to include all third-party libraries in system.config.js like this

```
 map: {
   'ng2-file-upload': 'npm:ng2-file-upload'
 },
 packages: {
  ng2-file-upload: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
```

This worked very fine for me.Now I am using angular cli and I am confused of including in it.

In angular-cli.json,

```
 "scripts": [
     ?????
  ],
```

Can any one please help me.Thanks

Comment: AFAIR you can import your scripts directly into your components and need not include then in your `angualr-cli.json` 

Eg: `import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/components/dropdown/dropdown';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store your dependencies in `node_modules` folder. When you need them, you import them inside a file using `import` statement. When compiled into JS, `import` are usually replaced with `require`.

When you code is being executed in a browser, you need a loader to load those files from `node_modules` and such loader is SystemJS. Learn more why SystemJS is needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669906/what-is-the-need-for-systemjs-in-angular2/40670147#40670147). SystemJS needs to know the path to modules, that's why you need to add dependencies to `system.config.js`.

However, `angular-cli` uses webpack module bundler, which has its own built-in loader. When webpack bundles files, it resolves paths and inlines them into resulting bundle. That's why you don't need to add paths anywhere when using `angular-cli`.

I just tried to use `ng2-tag-input` with `angular-cli`. Everything worked OK. I just imported the following into main module:

```
...
import {TagInputModule} from 'ng2-tag-input';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    TagInputModule, BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
```

And installed `@angular/animations`. And the following snippet worked OK:

```
@Component({
  template: '<tag-input [(ngModel)]='items'></tag-input>',
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Parmesan'];
}
```

You also need to install `@angular/animations`

Comment: Thats very interesting Maximus,Just now i am importing tags through npm in module.ts as like this import { TagInputModule } from 'ng2-tag-input';

Comment: but its not working.Should i need to import from the file or just the folder is enough

Comment: @MMR, can you be more specific? what's exactly not working? do you have a TS compilation error? or runtime error? or webpack error?

Comment: I am getting this as eerors    ............ng:///TagInputModule/TagInputComponent.ngfactory.js:369 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined(…)View_TagInputComponent_0 @ ng:///TagInputModule/TagInputComponent.ngfactory.js:369
ng:///TagInputModule/TagInputComponent.ngfactory.js:369 ERROR

Comment: can you setup a plunker? I'll try to reproduce locally

Comment: @MMR, just tried it myself. Everything worked fine. See my updated example for what I did.

Comment: I am getting this error    Cannot find module '@angular/animations/browser'.

Comment: @MMR, probably `@angular/animations` is missing, run `npm i @angular/animations`

Comment: Thanks you Maximus,I missed that animations.

Comment: Maximus,I had an another question can you pls answer if it is relevant to you?

Comment: @MMR, which one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535010/routerlink-not-working-in-grid-in-angular-2

Comment: @MMR, [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43535360/2545680) seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with SystemJS but:

Yes, you can add your libraries to the `scripts`

```
"scripts": [
    "pathToLibray"
]
```

But if you have a npm package, which is built for Angular you can use it without importing it. It gets loaded automatically from your `node_modules`

Hope I could help :)

Comment: Hi Raphael,Therefor if i had 20 .js file too I dont need to import in angular cli?Directly it works when i import it in my component?

Comment: Yes, it should.