# RouterLink not working in grid in angular 2

Tags: angular, datagridview, angular2-routing

Recently i started using jqwidgets [(here)](http://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-grid/index.htm) for my Angular project,
it worked well but the only problem is I put edit at each cell.To that edit button routerLink is not working.

My code,

```
this.columns =
[
    {
        text: 'Id', columntype: 'textbox', width: 80
    },
    {
        text: 'Name', columntype: 'textbox',datafield: 'name', width: 130
    },
    {
        text: 'Group Name', columntype: 'textbox', datafield: 'group_id', width: 130
    },
    {
        text: 'Actions',datafield: 'id', cellsrenderer: Action, width: 100
    }
];
```

This is my action function,

```
 var Action = function (row,datafield,value) {    
    return '<button ><a routerLink="pages/users">EDIT</a</button>'
 }
```

When i replace routerLink with href its working,can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that this widget will add your html code directly to the DOM. So angular is bypassed and it's not a "valid" angular-object and isn't handled/recognized by angular itself.

It's a problem of that widget, seems like you can't change that behavior.

Comment: Hi mxii,any solution do you suggest?