# How to manage front-end dependencies with bower in Angular 4.x app

Tags: angular, webpack, gulp, frontend

I had worked on angular 1.x project before where we used bower to manage and install front-end dependencies. We used a gulp build system, in which we used gulp-wiredep to wire up all dependencies in index.html.

Just recently, I have started working on Angular 4.x project and planning out to create a build system with gulp. Is that even possible? I know there are other options available like webpack, angular-cli etc... but is wish to create it using gulp.

My questions is:

1. How to manage the front-end dependencies?

Earlier when we used gulp, front-end dependencies were managed by bower and we used gulp-wiredep to wire all those up in index.html. But when I searched for Angular 4.x package in bower, I did't find one.

2. If I use SystemJs as a module loader, do I still have to reference all the js (ts->js) in index.html?

Earlier we had a gulp task which picked up all the js file referenced in index.html and bundled it into one app.js file.

Please help! I understand angular 4.x but I am finding a hard time with a build system.

Comment: did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44433517/2545680) help?

Answer (score 2):

> How to manage the front-end dependencies?

Use `npm` for that. [Bower is dying](https://www.quora.com/Is-Bower-dying).

> If I use SystemJs as a module loader, do I still have to reference all
>   the js (ts->js) in index.html?

No, you just have to reference the starting module, usually `main.js`. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669906/what-is-the-need-for-systemjs-in-angular2/40670147#40670147).

But I would strongly recommend to consider webpack/angular-cli for your build system.

Comment: Thanks! Could you point me to a repo. if you know any that exists, which uses webpack(config) for a real world angular 4 app? I need it as reference to be able to create my own one in my project. It should handle task of ts->js compilation, minifi. & concat., less to css, vendor prefixes, code analysis, cache busting,

Comment: @chirag_lad, there are many tutorials on the web, for example [this one](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

Comment: @chirag_lad, please consider upvoting or accepting my answer if it helped, thanks