# where to find systemjs.config.js in angular2 cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to update that file for adding 1 reference/dependency for 'angular2-in-memory-web-api' as the file and this ref is missing from my files?
Can anybody help me to create/find the same?
Thanks

Comment: there's no systemjs.config.js in angular-cli. it uses webpack

Answer (score 3):

`Angular-CLI` doesn't use `SystemJS` starting from the `Beta.12`. Read [this announcement](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.12). Hence there's no `systemjs.config.js` anymore. It uses `webpack` now.

> I need to update that file for adding 1 reference/dependency

With webpack you don't need to add anything to the configuration. Webpack resolves dependencies automatically during build type.

Comment: then how to resolve the issue regarding missing - 'angular2-in-memory-web-api. as it is needed

Comment: where is it required? what angular-cli version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 uses **webpack**, there is no `systemjs.config.js` in project created by angular2-cli.

More detailed explanation is here
[Differences between SystemJS and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38263593/3677277)